# Как реализовать вывод данных через UART на OLED дисплей?

Tags: c++, arduino

Преподаватель дал домой поработать с arduino (uno), но я не могу понять **как сделать вывод данных через UART на OLED** (SSD1307) дисплей.

Проблема в том, что ввожу 5, а выводит 53, 13, 10. На дисплеи соответственно 53, 13, 10; Ввожу 8, выводит 56, 13, 10.

Библиотека для дисплея: https://github.com/HobbyComponents/HCuOLED
Библиотке для SPI: https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/SPI

Может быть я неправильно подключил OLED?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "HCuOLED.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#define CS_DI 10
#define DC_DI 9
#define RST_DI 8

HCuOLED HCuOLED(SH1106, CS_DI, DC_DI, RST_DI); // For SH1106 displays (HCMODU0058 & HCMODU0059)

unsigned int i = 0;

char n;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  HCuOLED.Reset();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    delay(500);
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    n = Serial.read();
    delay(500);


    HCuOLED.Cursor(25, 4);
    HCuOLED.SetFont(MedProp_11pt);

    HCuOLED.Print(Serial.write(n));

  }
  HCuOLED.Rect(0, 0, 125, 63, OUTLINE);

  HCuOLED.Refresh();
  HCuOLED.ClearBuffer();
  delay(500);


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас read вводит символы, а println выводит десятичные коды символов этой строки.  То есть 53 это код пятёрки, а 13, 10 это CR, LF - "возврат каретки", "перевод строки"

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы выводилось, то что я ввожу? Это, я так понимаю ASCII, а как его конвертировать?

Comment: наоборот, вам его не надо конвертировать, а println конвертирует в коды, я не знаю этой библиотеки, но наверное там должно что-то быть, случайно функции write там нет?

Comment: Конечно есть `Serial.write(str) `

Comment: @PavelGridin У Вас n объявлена как int, а Вам нужно объявить её как char.

Comment: @PavelGridin , исправил. Да, действительно в UART выводит, то что надо, а на дисплей только "1". Как вывести из UART на экран, я не понял.
*Исправил код на новый